# How to perist only the first level of an entities hierarchy with Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, persistence

I'm migrating the DBAL of a ZF3 application to Doctrine and want to go ahead step by step. Currently I'm using a hierarchy of `Mapper` objects. Each entity in the like `FooEntity` hierarchy has an according `FooMapper`. Saving of nested entities is performed by nested `Mapper`s. Every `Mappers` saves its entity with `Zend\Db\Sql\Insert` or `Zend\Db\Sql\Update` and calls the proper `Mapper`s for the sub-entities like `BarMapper` for `BarEntity`.

Now, before I start with Doctrine's convenience features like `cascade={"persist"}`, I want to keep the `Mapper`'s hierarchy and just to perform the saving of the top level of the nested entity with `persist(...)` & `flush()`.

But when I try it

```
public function save(AbstractDataObject $dataObject)
{
    $newLogicalConnection = $this->logicalConnectionMapper->save($dataObject->getLogicalConnection());
    $newUser = $this->userMapper->save($dataObject->getUser());

    $dataObject->setLogicalConnection($this->entityManager->find(LogicalConnection::class, $newLogicalConnection->getId()));
    $dataObject->setUser($this->entityManager->find(User::class, $newUser->getId()));

    $this->entityManager->persist($dataObject);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $dataObject;
}
```

I get an error

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyNamespace\DataObject\AbstractEndpoint#externalServer' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: MyNamespace\DataObject\ExternalServer@000000006098ccff0000000068c23676. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'MyNamespace\DataObject\ExternalServer#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

So, Doctrine seems to try saving the whole entity with its sub-entities, and this attempt fails on one of the lower levels. But why? I have not activated any `cascade` options and expect Doctrine to save only the top level.

**Why does Doctrine try to save the whole entity and not only the top level? And how to get it saving only the top level of the given entity?**

Comment: I don't think there is a way.  The new entity error message is basically a warning that you need to enable cascade.  Given that you have a relationship between the two objects,  Doctrine will try to persist it.  You can of course remove the relationship mapping.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your comment. Maybe I understand the sense of `cascade={"persist"}` wrong. My expectation was/is, that with the `cascade={"persist"}` annotation the related objects get saved and without - not. But if the cascading saving works without `cascade={"persist"}` as well, what is the sense of this annotation?

Comment: Again it is a warning.  Some folks like to explicitly persist all the child entities in which case the cascade is not needed and the warning goes away.  One thing about Doctrine ORM in general is that it just does things in certain ways.  You either live with it or don't use it.  Personally, if I already had a working dbal based system then I'd stick with it.

Comment: @Cerad Well, is it possible to deactivate the cascading saving (but without to remove the relationships and their annotations)?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you have a new entity (not persisted yet) in `AbstractEndpoint->externalServer` and this field is not annotated as `cascade={"persist"}`

In other words you have just created a new entity `ExternalServer` and did not persisted it and added it as a relation to `AbstractEndpoint->externalServer` entity which is not annotated as `cascade={"persist"}`

So Doctrine ends up having this new entity and does not know what to do with it. In order not to lost any data this exception is raised.

To fix this you can do two things:

1. Add `$this->entityManager->persist($externalServer);` right after you create `ExternalServer` entity
2. Annotate `AbstractEndpoint->externalServer` with `cascade={"persist"}`. Which you don't want to do because you want only top level entity to be saved to DB so you need to persist it manually or DO NOT add it is a relation.

And now answering your question:

> But why? I have not activated any cascade options and expect Doctrine to save only the top level.

Somehow through relations in your object model Doctrine goes down to `ExternalServer` entity and finds it in unpersisted state. You can not save only top level of object hierarchy with link to unexisting record in relational database. If you do not want Doctrine to do it for you - you must handle this situations by yourself or remove not persisted entities from relations